# How to copy upto a specific line in a file to a new file using Java

Tags: java, java-8

This is my Java code which I am using to copy the notepad file content to a other notepad file.
Here I wants to do like, suppose I have 600000 lines in a notepad file and I only want to copy from line number 200000 to 500000 in another notepad file. Then what changes I have to make in this code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class FileCopy 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
   File fsrc=new File("C:\\\\Price.txt");         
  File fdes=new File("D:\\\\MyOutputFile.txt");        
  FileReader fr=new FileReader(fsrc);         
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr); 
  FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(fdes);       
  String s=null;
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fsrc);
  byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int)fsrc.length()];
  fis.read(byteArray);
  String data = new String(byteArray);
  String[] stringArray = data.split("\r\n");
  System.out.println("Number of lines in the file are ::"+stringArray.length);
  int lol=500;
  lol = stringArray.length;
  while((s=br.readLine())!=lol)             //Copying Content to the new file
  {
     fw.write(s);
     fw.write("\n");
     fw.flush();
   }
  System.out.println("File copied");
     fw.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Why can't you count the lines and stop when you get to the number you want to copy?

Comment: Use a BufferedReader.

Comment: I have tried with the above code but its giving error. Can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'd recommend you to take a look at this tutorial. You should use a BufferedReader instead of a FileInputStream.
[Tutorial on BufferedReader](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/bufferedreader)

Comment: I have tried BufferReader, but getting this error, can u help me to rectify the error.

Comment: Please post the code that is producing the error and the stack trace.